# netstat e on windows shows really high bytes count

Tags: netstat, netsh

running `netstat /e` is giving me strange results

"bytes received" from `netstat /e` output is always way higher, about 10 times higher than when `netsh interface ip show subinterfaces` is run. wireshark also shows similar number as the `netsh` command, am I using netstat /e` wrong?

thanks!

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with `netstat /e`?

Comment: i'm trying to find an accurate representation of byte count and packets received/sent